# How to capture an event in Celery

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I just started using Celery (more specifically django-celery) and I'm still not familiar with it.

I'm developing an application which will send tasks to be executed remotely in the workers, where each task takes about 3 min to finish. (Not heavy processing, web crawling stuff, but that's irrelevant).

When I send a task, I get a reference which can be used to fetch the results.

```
>>> result = task_name.delay()
>>> result
<AsyncResult: c34d78d8-b512-4165-9384-2b87933e33b7>
```

But, to know when the task have finished, I have to keep polling

```
>>> result.ready()
False
```

My idea, to avoid polling, is to listen for a [task-succeeded/task-failed](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/monitoring.html#task-events) event.
So, when I know that they have returned, I can continue the processing, without checking the database or continuously asking if it is ready.
(If anyone has a better suggestion for the task completion checking, I'd love to hear)

Not sure if I have some problem seeing the obvious, but, I don't get it how can I do this.

In [Celery Events docs](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/monitoring.html#id19), it says I should use a custom camera for that.
And that is another issue, as I intend to use django-celery's Django Admin Monitor.

So, finally: 
Can I capture an event without a camera? How?
If not, can I use it with django-celery's camera?

Comment: Was your question resolved or is it still unanswered? Do update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `on_success` and other handlers in `Task` is, it runs on the worker.  If you use this approach, the code you add to that method has to trigger the desired action; but the task doesn't have info about what process called it, so you would probably run another task ... that routes to the caller somehow ... that would wait in a queue to be executed ... doesn't sound like what you're looking for.

To get asynchronous notifications of task-level events, use `Celery.events.State` as demonstrated in http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=my_monitor#id20.  You can choose which events to monitor, and get real-time notification (callback-style) when an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Now the celery documentation isn't resolving for me at the moment, but it seems like you should be able to set up a callback method that your remote task can call to inform you that the task has completed.  I'll update this answer if/when I can get the celery documentation to resolve.

**EDIT:** Got to the documentation now.

So per [the documentation](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#handlers), it seems like what you want is a task class with either a `on_success` or `after_return` handler.  Depending on your use case, either this method can do the processing you need to do using the return value of the task, or it can notify you that the result has succeeded.  I would recommend the former unless you have a specific need to run on the handler instead of the worker.  Regardless, either way, you shouldn't need to poll `result.ready()` anymore.

Comment: Actually, I do need to do the processing on the handler.
I tried `after_return()`, but this one will be executed on the worker side.
I'll try `on_success()` now.

Comment: I believe `after_return` is called on the handler, so that should give you the capability you need.  If you need to be in the same context (block) where you started the task, you're probably going to a) need to do polling, or b) may actually need to be doing this as a synchronized subtask, and create the block as a new task designed to run on the handler.

Comment: Reading up on cameras, they're really designed for monitoring the environment of your tasks as a whole (the size of queues, the status of all tasks, etc), not for monitoring individual tasks themselves.

Comment: Well, `on_success` behaved just like `after_return`. I wrote just a print statement, and their output its on worker side.
I mean, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use the answer in the same context, but mostly I didn't want to use polling (a), nor to worry about the task again before it is ready. Using another task (b) would not return, as the post processing needs to access data locally, unaccessible to external workers.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure then.  I'm primarily coming from a background on a different tasking system, so I expected the callbacks to execute differently.  So I'm reaching the end of my depth at this point.  **:-/** Can you explain why you need to run on the handler?

Comment: Ok, so a camera may be out of question. But, is there a way to listen to the events without them?
I understand there may be, cause in the docs for [celery/events/snapshot](https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/celery/events/snapshot.py) _Consuming the events as a stream is not always suitable
    so this module implements a system to take snapshots..._. So, we could listen to them as a stream, right?

Comment: Well if you look at the code you linked to, they're using the `self.time.apply_interval` on line 50 to essentially implement polling.  So I'm not sure they've got a truly better solution.

Comment: Before sending the task, I open a config file stored locally (each task will have its own) extract some data. Send the task with extracted data. Task executes and return additional data. This data must be processed again, following directions still on config file. After later processing, save data to file, and store a reference to it on database. Very roughly, thats the idea.